# Google colab not opening

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a problem using google colaboratory for a project of mine, 
when I open the notebook from my drive it gives an error saying:

```
> Notebook loading error There was an error loading this notebook.
> Ensure that the file is accessible and try again. Network error during
> initial load.
> 
> https://drive.google.com/drive/?action=locate&id=1l6F5WlTPY02vxhnF3jhKOXCKpAL2CDm5&authuser=0
> Network error during initial load. Error: Network error during initial
> load.
>     at new XC (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:205811)
>     at Object.HE.c.b (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:233858)
>     at GC (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:200132)
>     at FC.vc (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:196064)
>     at xE.DC.close (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:195877)
>     at XMLHttpRequest.f.onreadystatechange (https://colab.research.google.com/v2/external/realtime_binary.js?vrz=colab-20180830-085619-RC01_210970148:1:231717)
```

The problem seems to be associated with browser cookies, as when I open the link in Incognito mode it works, but when I sign in to my google account (I can't run the notebook unless I'm signed in), the same error message appears.
The notebook on the drive has "All who has the link can edit" access control on it.
I also want to note that I'm from Sudan, might google colab be blocked from Sudan?

Answer (score 0):

If loading works in an incognito window, that's a hint that an extension might be the problem.